# Display multiple map fragments in an activity simultaneously

Tags: java, android, supportmapfragment

I have an activity which holds multiple addresses (Street, City, Country, Postcode) and displays them to the user. Under each address, I want to display a `MapFragment`, passing in the address information and display the point to the user on the map.

When I tried it, the app crashed and I got the below error. It points me to where I inflate the parent layout which holds all address instances.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #45: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0211, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Is there a way to workaround this error and/or display multiple `MapFragments` otherwise?

**Edit:** I want my layout to look something like this. I can show multiple text entries, but once I try to add 2 mapFragments, I get a crash.

XML code:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_address_info"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/contact_address_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_address_info"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/contact_address_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_address_info"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/contact_address_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Java code:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment1;
        mapFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        if (mapFragment1 != null) mapFragment1.getMapAsync(this);

                SupportMapFragment mapFragment2;
                mapFragment2 = (SupportMapFragment)
         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
                if (mapFragment2 != null) mapFragment2.getMapAsync(this);

                SupportMapFragment mapFragment3;
                mapFragment3 = (SupportMapFragment)
         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map3);
                if (mapFragment3 != null) mapFragment3.getMapAsync(this);
```

[image]

Comment: can you share some of your code to make it understand better?

Comment: @VinayJayaram Hi, yes, please see edited question.

Comment: see if this link helps you https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/supportmapfragment-in-fragment/

Comment: "Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically." I already use <include> to add the address entry, so I guess I will have to add the MapFragment the the included layout dynamically. I'll give it a try!